# Question with CSS horizontal bar and div borders not aligning

Tags: html, css

You can see in these screenshots

[Image 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Tz0gs.png)
[Image 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nkstc.png)

I have two questions:

1. Why is there a horizontal scrollbar?
2. You can see on the second image (a zoomed version of the first one) the green border and orange border is not aligned properly, **why?**

Here is demo:

```css
.app{
  height:100%;
  width: 100%;
}

html, #root, body{
  height:100%;
  margin:0px;
}

.header{
  height: 50px;
  width:100%;
  border:1px solid green;

}

.app-body{
  display: flex;
  height: calc(100% - 55px);
}

.menu{
  height:100%;
  border:1px solid green;
  width:100px;
}

.content{
  flex:1;
  height:100%;
  border:1px solid orange;
}
```

```html
<div class="app">
  <div class="header"></div>
  <div class="app-body">
    <div class="menu"></div>
    <div class="content"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Welcome to SO!

That is because you need to add `box-sizing: border-box`.

According to [Mozilla MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/box-sizing):

> **border-box** tells the browser to account for any border and padding in the values you specify for an element's width and height. If you set an element's width to 100 pixels, that 100 pixels will include any border or padding you added, and the content box will shrink to absorb that extra width. This typically makes it much easier to size elements.

Look at this demo:

```css
.header, .menu, .content {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.app{
  height:100%;
  width: 100%;
}

html, #root, body{
  height:100%;
  margin:0px;
}

.header{
  height: 50px;
  width:100%;
  border:1px solid green;

}

.app-body{
  display: flex;
  height: calc(100% - 55px);
}

.menu{
  height:100%;
  border:1px solid green;
  width:100px;
}

.content{
  flex:1;
  height:100%;
  border:1px solid orange;
}
```

```html
<div class="app">
  <div class="header"></div>
  <div class="app-body">
    <div class="menu"></div>
    <div class="content"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

To understand what happens, you need to know that the sizing of the element by default, is determined by its content.

For example, if we have a div (div is by default a block, so it has 100% width) and add around it 1px border, then what will happen is the div will have an additional 2px to its width, because as I mentioned before - the element is sized by its element (box). To avoid it, we can tell the browser that we don't want to size our element by its content. We can tell the browser we want to size it as a `border-box`, which will not overlap the width when we add additional pixels to the element when we add padding / border.

In your example, your header was a div (meaning, it had 100% width), and it had an additional border (+1 from the left border, and +1 form the right border), in total it had 100% + 2px width.

your `.header` has the sibling `.app-body`. App body is a block too, therefore it has 100% width. Unlike the header, `.app-body` doesn't have a border, so it stays in total 100% width.

`.app-body` has 2 children. both of them has borders. You're probably asking yourself, how they didn't affect their parent. Well, that's because their parent is a block, and it will not be affected by its children. This is why his children didn't affect his width.

Comment: thanks why in my example the green box was actually wider than orange one?

Comment: @dave That's because it had 100% width + 1px for the left border, and +1px for the right border. In total 100% + 2px;

Comment: Yes but same logic had to be applied to orange box isn't it, so why wasn't it wider?

Comment: Oh. because the menu and the content were relative to app-menu width which was 100% (compared to the header that was 100% + 2px).

Comment: @Elyia Cohen: Which is app-menu? I don't have such class :( please explain that part more clearly because that is what confused me.

Comment: I'm so sorry, I meant app-body. Your app body didn't have border, so no matter what, it had 100% width. But! your header had a border, so it had 100% + 2px. Is that clearer?

Comment: @dave look at the updated answer. I believe it's fully covered for you now. If you still don't understand, then let me know.

Comment: So the width of the app-body is 1 pixel less than the green border of header right? And the widths of app-bodys children (menu and content) had to fit *within* this length right? (e.g. the orange border had no right to go wider than width of app-header - so the content width was 1 px smaller)

Comment: the width of the app-body is **2 pixels**. Remember, one because of the left border and one for the right border. About the rest - you're right.

Comment: yeah i meant width of app body is 2 pixels less than the width of the green bordered box

Comment: bottom line is I think say width of app-body is X. Now if we put another div inside it, that div must fit inside app-body. And in our case it happens that width of app-body is 2 pixels less than the green box, am I right? Hence when we put additionally something inside app-box one sees that that is *even* shorter in length than the green box

Comment: @dave I guess everyone has its own way of describing. In case you feel you can improve a given answer, you're always welcomed to do so.

Comment: I think you also missed the point that display:flex is playing role here, it ordered children of app-body to stay within the bounds of itself!

Answer (score 1):

To fix the horizontal scroll bar you should use `box-sizing: border-box` property. Box sizing defines what is width property contains. Value `box-sizing` says that the width includes border width and padding.

Your css after adding box-sizing.

```
.app{
  height:100%;
  width: 100%;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

html, #root, body{
  height:100%;
  margin:0px;
}

.header{
  height: 50px;
  width:100%;
  border: 1px solid green;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.app-body{
  display: flex;
  height: calc(100% - 55px);
}

.menu{
  height:100%;
  border:1px solid green;
  width:100px;
}

.content{
  flex:1;
  height:100%;
  border:1px solid orange;
}
```

[Link to fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/pjtrb5Ly/1/)
[Box sizing property described](https://www.w3schools.com/CSSref/css3_pr_box-sizing.asp)